# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cglib.transform.impl.MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy after rebuilding

Tags: java, spring, classnotfoundexception

I have this strange error when trying to run my project on Tomcat. Until a few days ago, everything was ok, and I haven't changed any line of code since then. The only thing I did before everything began to fail was "Update project..." in Maven context menu.

```
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;.
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:48 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ACME' did not find a matching property.
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 549 ms
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2013-08-21 16:39:55,109 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'converters' while setting bean property 'converters'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters': Cannot create inner bean 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' of type [converters.AuthorityToStringConverter] while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/converters.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters': Cannot create inner bean 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' of type [converters.AuthorityToStringConverter] while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/converters.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/converters.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1492)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cglib.transform.impl.MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 46 more
2013-08-21 16:39:55,109 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'converters' while setting bean property 'converters'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters': Cannot create inner bean 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' of type [converters.AuthorityToStringConverter] while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/converters.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters': Cannot create inner bean 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' of type [converters.AuthorityToStringConverter] while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/converters.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/converters.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1492)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cglib.transform.impl.MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 46 more
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'converters' while setting bean property 'converters'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters': Cannot create inner bean 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' of type [converters.AuthorityToStringConverter] while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/converters.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters': Cannot create inner bean 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' of type [converters.AuthorityToStringConverter] while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/converters.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converters.AuthorityToStringConverter#376fcff8' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/converters.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1492)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cglib.transform.impl.MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 46 more

Aug 21, 2013 4:39:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ACME] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/ACME] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/ACME] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 21, 2013 4:39:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6432 ms
```

Comment: Solve this : nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy You can find this class in spring-core.jar

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to solve this exception. What is supposed that I have to do with this class?

Comment: To solve your exception, you just have to add spring-core.jar in your WEB-INF/lib. What you're supposed to do with this class remains a mystery to me : I don't know what your project is ;)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solve the exception. Everything worked fine a few days ago, so even I doesn't know what's the purpose of this class.

Comment: How is your POM.xml ?

Comment: Hi, finally solved. There was an error in the POM file. Wrong Spring version in dependencies.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following class that cannot be found:

`org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy`

It was added to spring-core **3.2.4** and is not yet present in spring-core **3.2.3**.

Make sure you do not accedently include an old version of spring core in your project while using newer versions of other spring-* libraries.

Comment: Hi, as I stated above, that was the problem, wrong spring version. Thanks for your time.

Comment: For maven users, the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821155/maven-spring-4-spring-security) question will help maven sort things out with regards to the spring security and framework versions being different.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exception, and in my case it was `spring-security` `3.2.5.RELEASE` including `spring-aop` `3.2.8.RELEASE`, which didn't work with `spring 4.1.4.RELEASE` and `cglib` `3.1`.

To solve the problem I've just included `spring-aop` directly to force the version I wanted, adding to my pom, the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my case, I've the property `spring.version` set to  `4.1.4.RELEASE`.

After rebuilding it all worked since the new version doesn't require `MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy` any more.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything worked fine a few days ago

That sounds familiar. Have you added a new dependency that also has spring-core.jar included?
If so, exclude this spring-core dependency in your pom.xml from the newly added dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Resolution to this problem would depend on your pom.xml and what Spring library it has. 
Some rejig of the spring jars including and excluding Spring jars in maven will resolve this.

I added the following to resolve the mongo-db spring-data jar related issue.

```
    <properties>
            <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <spring.data.version>1.6.1.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
            <spring.core.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.core.version>
        </properties>

    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>   
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.core.version}</version>                           
            </dependency>

                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <version>${mongo.driver.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jongo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jongo</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```