# Maven : Spring 4 + Spring Security

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-4

Can you explain to me how to properly build a web app with Spring? I know that the latest version of Spring framework is 4.0.0.RELEASE, but the latest version of Spring Security is 3.2.0.RELEASE, and it depends on spring 3.2.6... maybe i'm wrong :)

How can I integrate it with Maven?
  Can I use Spring 4 or must I use the previous version?
  What is the proper way?

If it`s not hard for you could you show me you pom.xml?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should be fine using Spring 4. As described in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom):

"*Spring Security builds against Spring Framework 3.2.6.RELEASE, but is also tested against Spring Framework 4.0.0.RELEASE. This means you can use Spring Security 3.2.0.RELEASE with Spring Framework 4.0.0.RELEASE.*"

They go on to describe strategies for integrating Spring 4 with Spring Security in your project. Like this one:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks, it`s what i want)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck with your project!

Comment: hi @Vidya, what about Spring Framework 4.0.2.RELEASE ?