# Spring MVC JdbcTemplate Transactional Annotation does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I have two insert operation in one http post request. something like

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public int create(final Student student) {
        // insert into table 1

        // insert into table 2 using id return from insert 1, but something BAD happen here
    }
}
```

so, I added `@Transactional` at method level as shown above.

In order to make it work, I added this `tx:annotation-driven`

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

so my `app-servlet.xml` looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/res/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/AppDb" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
</beans>
```

the `component-scan` will basically scan **all** class include `controller`, `service`, `model`, `viewmodel`, `helper` class etc.

If I remove the `tx:annotation-driven`, the `@transactional` won't work.
But once I add this `tx:annotation-driven`, some error starts to appear, like

```
Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.app.service.StudentService com.app.controller.HomeController.studentRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentService' defined in file [/path/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MathSchool/WEB-INF/classes/com/app/service/StudentService.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cglib/transform/impl/MemorySafeUndeclaredThrowableStrategy
```

How can I make this `@transactional` work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve this weird error with Tomcat, Spring and Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361136/how-to-solve-this-weird-error-with-tomcat-spring-and-maven)

Comment: @Jens I have spring-core jar included.

Comment: Do you have also spring-aop included?

Comment: @Jens Yes, spring-aop-3.2.13.RELEASE

Comment: You have to add the same version of spring aop as your spring core is.

Comment: @Jens Because I'm using spring-security-web 3.2.7.RELEASE, the aop 3.x is automatically added.

Comment: Use spring-security-web version 4.0.0.RELEASE. That will be compatible with spring core 4.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: @Jens I didn't upgrade spring security to version 4, because more materials, question/answer on version 3, I need to study the migration as well which takes more time. I downgrade my spring to 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3636601/jens)

My project using `spring 4.1.6` and `spring security 3.2.7`

According to this documentation [Migrating from Spring Security 3.x to 4.x (XML Configuration)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html)

> Spring Security 4 now requires Spring 4 (Spring 4.0 or 4.1, I guess). Conveniently, Spring Security
>   3.2.x works with Spring 3.2.x and Spring 4 (Spring 4.0 Only, I guess).

The only thing I did is downgrade `Spring 4.1` to `Spring 4.0`